# Angular ui-router nested views not showing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this configuration for my states, but when i enter to /account/login directly it doesn´t work just shows a blank page, i need always to enter first to /account/ and then type /account/login to make it work.

I have this configuration:

```
.state('account',{
    url: "/account",
    views:{
        mainViewer:{
            templateUrl      :   'app/main/account/account/account.view.html',
            controller       :   'accountController',
            resolve          :   { load: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad){ return $ocLazyLoad.load( {name: 'app.accountController', files:['app/main/account/account/account.controller.js'] } ); }]}
        }
    }
})
.state('account.login',{
    url: "/login",
    parent: "account",
    views:{
        loginregister:{
            templateUrl      :   'app/main/account/login/login.view.html',
            controller       :   'loginController',
            resolve          :   { load: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad){ return $ocLazyLoad.load( {name: 'app.homeController', files:['app/main/account/login/login.controller.js'] } ); }]}
        }
    }
})
```

The index has the ui-view for account and the account html file has the ui-view for the login, but i can't acces directly to login

Comment: Using HTML5 mode in the `$locationProvider`?

Comment: No i`m not  using it in that way